# sending formatted email addresses in GAE

Tags: php, google-app-engine, email

this is fine in GAE Python:

```
sender="Example.com Support <support@example.com>"
```

but will throw `invalid sender` in PHP, I only seem to be able to send emails if I specify:

```
sender="support@example.com"
```

has anyone had any success with this under PHP, or can anyone at GAE expand on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue in GAE PHP, you can track it at https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=10153